# Adding a variable onto a header redirect in php?

Tags: php, variables, redirect

So far I have...

```
   $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['email']));
$details = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $details['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $details['email'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $details['email'];
header('location:/home?account='.$details[\'username\']');
exit();
```

I want to add the username to the query string for each individual login. Where am I going wrong??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why are you sending the username to the redirected page? why not just check the session variable?

Comment: It is my login script, that is where the user goes to once they successfully login. those session variables are created when they login for authentification to stay logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's

```
header('Location: /home?account='.$details['username']);
```

Comment: Please make use of the function [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) for a more defensive data handling. Additionally, the [`Location` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) needs an absolute URL to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location:/home?account=$details['username']");
```

and you should use the full url nor a relative one

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Answer (score 0):

`header('location:/home?account='.$details['username']);`

; )

Comment: that's not a good advice as ``header()`` has some standards! ``Location`` must be with an capital ``L``

Comment: actually its  http ... or what ever scheme your using.

Comment: ye I typed that but it turned it into a link, does it really matter, and plus I am in localhost anyhow atm

Comment: @carlgcode: locahost still is http, you just need an absolute URL, the full address of the page you want to redirect to, like `http://localhost/home?account=...`.

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location:/home?account={$details['username']}");` should work fine.